# Update Table by getting maximum value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following configuration:

```
CREATE TABLE `extRef` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `extType` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `extId` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I would like to migrate some data from this table, effectively,

For reach unique (extType,extId) pair, get the maximum Id value.

I have the following setup already:

```
CREATE TABLE cleanupTbl(
    retainableId BIGINT(20),
    extId BIGINT(20),
    extType BIGINT(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (retainableId, extId, extType)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO cleanupTbl(extId, extType )
SELECT r.`extId`, r.`extType `
FROM `extRef` r
GROUP BY r.`extType `, r.`extId`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Now, when I try to insert the Maximum Id i have tried the following setups but none seem to be working due to errors. Can someone please help with a working statement? Thanks

```
UPDATE `cleanupTbl` cl
SET cl.`retainableId` = temp.`largestId`
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(r.`id`) AS largestId
    FROM `extRef` r
    JOIN `cleanupTbl` c
    ON  c.`extId` = r.`extId` AND c.`extType ` = r.`extType `
) temp;
```

or

```
UPDATE cl
SET cl.`retainableId` = MAX(r.`id`)
FROM `cleanupTbl` AS cl
INNER JOIN `extRef` AS r
ON cl.`extId` = r.`extId` AND cl.`extType` = r.`extType`;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining to an already filtered (maxID,extID,extType) table and then update accordingly:

```
UPDATE `cleanupTbl` cl
INNER JOIN(SELECT MAX(r.`id`) AS largestId, r.`extId`, r.`extType `
           FROM `extRef` r
           GROUP BY r.`extType `,r.`extId`) temp
ON cl.`extId` = temp.`extId` AND cl.`extType ` = temp.`extType `
SET cl.`retainableId` = temp.`largestId`
```

Comment: I can't yet. need to wait some time to be able to